# IOS Swift Objective-c Zoom to point other than center rampToVideoZoomFactor

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avcapturesession

Currently setting zoom level zooms on the center of the image, and an even amount is cropped off of the top/bottom and right/left sides.

```
captureDevice!.rampToVideoZoomFactor(4, withRate: 3.5)
```

Is it possible to zoom on a point other than center?